# Problems with current location pin

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, cllocationmanager

I'm working on an app that shows a couple of places on the map along with the user's current position.
I have two small problems with it:

- First off, I want the current location pin to be the default blue circle, but it shows a green pin just like the other locations.
- Second problem, whenever I touch the screen, the current location pin drops again. It just can't seem to be steady like the other ones. It's like it's being called whenever I interact with the app.

Comment: Show your viewForAnnotation method.  For the second problem: are you adding the user location annotation manually or using the map view's showsUserLocation setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set your mapView delegate to self...that should fix the pin color.  Not sure about your other problem

// in the viewDidLoad
[mapView setDelegate:self];

where "mapView" is defined as "IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;"

Comment: Hello, i tried setting the delegate to self, didn't work, here's my code: